# How to draw a line to connect two pins on a map?

Tags: ios, dictionary, mkmapview, pins

I placed two pins on a map:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D cord1 = {.latitude = 44.508473, .longitude =  11.375828};
    CLLocationCoordinate2D cord2 = {.latitude = 44.508871, .longitude =  11.375854};

    [self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(cord1, MKCoordinateSpanMake(.005, .005)) animated:YES];
    [self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(cord2, MKCoordinateSpanMake(.005, .005)) animated:YES];


    AddressAnnotation * annotazione = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] init];
    AddressAnnotation * annotazione2 = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] init];

    [annotazione setCoordinate:cord1];
    [annotazione2 setCoordinate:cord2];

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotazione];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotazione2];
}
```

Is there a way to connect pins with a line? Thank you!

Comment: [Google "CoreGraphics iOS draw line".](http://google.com/search?q=CoreGraphics+iOS+draw+line)

Comment: I saw it but...isn't there an easier way? I've just to connect pins, no route, google or other complications...

Comment: I don't think `CGContextAddLines(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), twoPoints, 2);` is particularly difficult...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MKPolyline` has the method `polylineWithCoordinates:count:`, which takes a number of coordinates. You already have the two coordinates you need (`cord1` and `cord2`) to create a polyline. Add the overlay to your map and implement `mapView:viewForOverlay:` to return an overlay view.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 4.x, Apple added support for map overlays. It might help to read a little bit more about the MKPolyline & MKPolylineView classes and the mapView:viewForOverlay: method defined in the MKMapViewDelegate protocol. All available in the Map Kit Framework Reference.